# Add quotes or brackets around selection in doom-emacs

Tags: doom, delimiters

I used to use `Spacemacs` and it had this nifty feature where a selection could be bracketed with quotes, parentheses or any similar pair characters by simply pressing the character.

So `UpdateJob` could be converted to `"UpdateJob"` by selecting the name and pressing <kbd>"</kbd>. Or `setq-default line-spacing 0.3` could be converted to `(setq-default line-spacing 0.3)` by selecting the entire text and pressing <kbd>(</kbd>

How do I do this with `doom-emacs`

Answer (score 2):

Emacs 24 came with [electric-pair-mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ElectricPair)

You can enable it globally with `(electric-pair-mode 1)`